# Do I need to check on wiki for unknown terms in Dune?

Tags: dune

I just started to read Dune, the terms and content is like bizarre to me. There are special terms without previous introduction of its nature. For example: Muad'Dib, Gom jabber( fortunately, it was later revealed as a poison needle ), quasi-fief, faufreluches, Kull wahad, etc.

If I google them, I will find them in Dune wiki with good explaination, but do I need to look it up?

Comment: Having misread the title of this question gave me the idea of creating a little community-wiki question here to make such a glossary. However, I am not certain whether that’s a good idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

There is a glossary at the end of the book. The Wiki might contain spoilers so stick to the book.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.  The book uses all these made-up terms in such an off-hand way because there are handy definitions at the end of the book.

Comment: It's not actually in all editions, but it is in almost all. I've encountered a hardcover library edition sans glossary and timeline.

Comment: @aramis interessting. When I first read Dune, my library didn't even have a hardcover version at all :D

Answer (score 16):

No, they'll be explained enough in context. Besides, this way you get to feel some of Paul's confusion and wonder at his strange new world.

(Besides, *quasi-fief* doesn't have an entry on the [Dune wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) -- probably because its parts are in any English-language dictionary.)